# Match rounding behavour of sprintf

Tags: c++

I'm currently presented a rounded output to the user using `sprintf`.

The application needs to make decisions based on this value as seen by the user so the user can verify the application is working correctly. Currently no rounding is used internally so when the user sees a result of 9.8, the internal code sees something like 9.7999999999999996 which isn't equal to 9.8

Looking around I couldn't find a round function in C++, although lots of nice examples of how to round are presented I'm concerned they may not exactly match what `sprintf` will do in all cases.

So currently I'm using the output of `sprintf` converted back to a number to control my logic.

Any suggestions for a cleaner approach? (using presentation functions for logic feels wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider floor and do something like this:

```
float p = 7.9999996;
float q= floor((p+0.005)*100)/100;
```

which rounds in two digits x.xx

For negative numbers you'll need to use ceil in same way :)